# Where Calculated Field performs better in QuickSight, in Dataset or in Visuals?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I can add Calculated Field in Amazon QuickSight in three places:

Option 1: In Athena Query and add that as a view. Then refer that view as QuickSight Dataset and use that into Visuals

Option 2: In QuickSight Dataset and use that into Visuals

Option 3: In QuickSight Visuals directly

I wonder, where to place the calculated field is best option if I consider the dashboard performance. Anyone can share their views?

I tried to place that into Athena end and in the Dataset end. To me seems same. Only little slowness I found in loading of website, when I placed that into Athena end. But I am not sure, where I should place that ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to create the custom dimensions in Athena and then query them from QuickSight. Performance might be a bit worse this way (because you're transferring more data), but you can avoid vendor lock-in (if you want to change the BI tool, you don't have to rebuild the dataset). I calculate the fields directly in the visuals only if they are aggregations (sum, count, etc.)